# With the eclipse remote debugging tool, where do I specify a custom idenity file and username to connect?

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

The dialog in the eclipse java remote debugging tool only offers fields for 'host' and 'port'.

To connect to the server using ssh, I need to also specify a custom identity file (the ssh '-i' flag), and a username.

Answer (score 0):

A way to get it working is to use the ssh -L flag to create a local redirect.

For example, with cygwin, issue:

```
ssh -i /cygdrive/c/Users/yourUserName/.ssh/someKeyFile.pem -L 7999:localhost:8000 ubuntu@11.22.33.44
```

then, in eclipse, your 'host' will be 'localhost', and 'port' will be '7999'.

on the remote server, you'll launch with a flag like:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

to have that java process listen on the remote server on port 8000.

Comment: @Kayaman - updated to reflect your sentiment on 'workaroundish-ness'